# Polling every ~100ns in bash

Tags: linux, bash, real-time

Maybe the problem is trivial and on any regular `uC` it'd be for me.

I have some very simple bash script in infinite loop. I just need some value change every certain amount of time like in `uC` with `TIM` interruption handler but in bash.

Every f.e. 1 ms the loop is in the very begining, no matter how long script took (but for sure less than that). It's why `sleep` doesn't work for me. After all instructions from loop are done scheduler doesn't go back to my script untill this 1 ms passed, also I don't want scheduler to switch process while doing the script. I hope I'm understandable.

Also, `watch` command isn't an option neither, beocuse I want it within script, and have a process still running instead have it done and run it again and again.

Comment: What is uC? What is TIM interruption handler? Can you edit your question and add your bash script?

Comment: Bash script is really not the pont here, let's say it's just: 
while true
do echo "Hello"
done
uC is microcontroler like MCS51, ATMega, STM32 ect.
TIM is Timer incorporated to the hardwere structure of microcontroler which can runn in  certain frequncy and when overflowed an interruption occur and main program stops and "interruption handling" program is execiuted. (f.e. read voltage every 100 ns and put it to memory is most of the time realised on low lewel in this way).
I want to do something like this in bash. Run some "timer" in background which will handle code every n ns

Comment: Please add an example of the code you are currently running, what is the result / output you are expecting, and where may there be a point of failure, to make it possible for anyone who reads your question to provide an answer to it.

Comment: bash isn't designed for any kind of real-time processing. The only timing constructs it has are approximate ones, and the mechanisms it has for calling non-builtin code are extremely high-overhead to boot (and will add far more jitter to invocation times than anything called "real-time" could possibly tolerate). It's simply the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: BTW -- if I were trying to pick a reasonably high-level language to do microcontroller work today, I'd probably choose [Rust](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/).

Comment: ...but anyhow -- this is like going to Electricians StackExchange and asking to how to use a log of wood as a radio coil, and by the way you need it tuned to a precise frequency. You won't get a good answer because there _is_ no good answer given the constraints placed on the question.

Comment: I got that, I'm working now on patching kernel (or building custom kernel) with RT managment co-kernel xenomai. I'll see if I can make it work.